# C# Lambda Expressions Using Complex Objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, visual-studio-2015

How can I use a Lambda Expression on a List of `Payment` objects that have a List `PaymentFields` object.  Here's what I currently have.

`var list = paymentList.Where(payment => payment.PaymentFields.Any(field => field.FieldName == "ItemA" && field.FieldValue == "50");`

That gives me payments that have ItemA as the Field Name and 50 as the Field Value.  However, I want to COMPARE the two PaymentFields like so...

`Where FieldName == "ItemA" && FieldValue = "50" && FieldName ItemA < FieldName ItemB`

How would I do this?

**I have two Objects:**

```
public class Payment
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public List<PaymentFields> PaymentFields { set; get; }
}

public class PaymentFields
{
    public string FieldName { set; get; }
    public string FieldValue { set; get; }
}
```

**Here is an example Object:**

```
var payment = new Payment()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test",
    PaymentFields = new List<PaymentFields>()
    {
        new PaymentFields()
        {
            FieldName = "ItemA",
            FieldValue = "20"
         },
         new PaymentFields()
         {
             FieldName = "ItemB",
             FieldValue = "50"
          }
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know for sure there will be two payment fields per payment?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, yes. Which is why I have a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure there will be an "ItemA" and "ItemB", then this will work.

If either "ItemA" or "ItemB" is missing, it will throw an exception.

```
var list = paymentList
             .Where(payment => payment.PaymentFields.Any(field => field.FieldName == "ItemA" && field.FieldValue == "50")
             .Where(payment => payment.PaymentFields.First(field => field.FieldName == "ItemA").FieldValue
                                   <
                               payment.PaymentFields.First(field => field.FieldName == "ItemB").FieldValue)
                    );
```